# How to detect if the Control.Click event was by the mouse, keyboard, or something else?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, click

How can I tell if a [`Control.Click`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx) event was triggered by the mouse or by the keyboard?

#### Edit:

Handling `MouseClick` and `KeyPress` does't work for me, because then how would I know if something else triggered the click? (e.g. `PerformClick`)

Comment: The `Click` event can also be fired by `PerformClick`, without necessarily either keyboard or mouse input.

Comment: why ask such a question, when you have knowledge of delegates and advanced stuff... and it can be by neither

Comment: @Ben: I forgot to mention the "other" category, yeah -- that's actually the reason why I asked, since I can't just ignore other kinds of clicks. (@Marino: it's not that trivial of a question, because of what Ben mentioned.)

Answer (score 6):

You can't.  Use the [Control.MouseClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick.aspx) event and the [Control.KeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) event so you can tell the source of the event.  And remember that a space on the control with focus and a Ctrl+ key can generate a click on a button as well.

Comment: `Control.KeyPress` will be raised repeatedly if the key is held down.  I think it would be better to use `Control.KeyUp`.

Answer (score 4):

You can not tell, but you can use MouseClick and KeyPress if you need to know what originated the event.

```
void handler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool mouseEvent = (e is MouseEventArgs);
    bool keyEvent = (e is KeyEventArgs);
    bool performClick = (e is EventArgs) && !keyEvent && !mouseEvent;
}
```